# Boost ASIO Access Violation on destruction of io_service

Tags: c++, sockets, visual-c++, boost, boost-asio

I am currently working on a project where I create a `boost::asio::ip::udp::socket` and set it up to asynchronously listen for data from clients. I am using CMake to generate my project files for both Linux and Windows 10 deployment environments.

I have no problems with the code running on Linux with GCC and Clang, however, when I run in `Release` mode with MSVC and Visual Studio than I get an access violation when the program is exiting.

Here is the error that I am getting:

```
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFB51954989 (ntdll.dll) in Weave_Server.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x0000000000000024.
```

[image]

The stack shows that this exception is happening on the destruction of my `NetworkManager` class:

[image]

EDIT: Here is the destrcutor for the object that has my `udp::socket` and `io_service` object. The full destructor gets called and the error is coming from somewhere in either the `io_service` being destroyed or the `udp::socket` being cleaned up. The `udp::socket` is a `std::shared_ptr` and will be destroyed when this function goes out of scope:
[image]

Through some research I know that `ntdll.dll` is for debugging symbols of Visual Studio C++ projects, which makes sense why it would crash in Release mode (because debugging symbols shouldn't be loaded).

Why would the project be trying to access any debugging symbols from inside a release mode project? Is this a setting that I need to set in the CMake file?

Here is where I get boost in my `CMakeLists.txt` for the project:

```
if ( MSVC )
    set( Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS          ON  ) 
else()
    set( Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS          OFF  )
endif()
set( Boost_DETAILED_FAILURE_MSG     ON  )    # Useful error messages from boost
set( Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME       OFF )    
set( Boost_DEBUG                    OFF )    # Print debug info from find boost

FIND_PACKAGE( Boost COMPONENTS system regex REQUIRED )

if( Boost_FOUND )
    message( STATUS      "Success, Boost found!" )
else()
    message( ERROR      "Cannot find boost! Exiting..." )
    return()
endif()
```

Another thing I can think of is changing if Boost is statically or dynamically linked, but I have changed the `BOOST_USE_STATIC_LIBS` and the same error occurs in both settings.

Does anyone have any ideas as to why this exception is being thrown, or some settings to check for Debug vs Release that I am missing? Thanks

Comment: From the picture I would look at the destructor line 23 and see if you can tell why it causes a null pointer dereferecnce.

Comment: Make sure you are using release binaries for your release configuration and debug binaries for your debug configuration. In Visual Studio it is important to not mix these for `c++` based code.

Comment: When I compiled boost and specified my toolset to `msvc`, the libraries were generated with `-gd` for debug or nothing for release. In the visual studio project I didn't need to add any `Additional Dependencies`, just add a `Additional Library Directory` folder. Could it be possible that MSVC would be trying to link against the debug `lib` files?

Comment: Its probably automatically linking using the pragma.

Comment: I have seen the `pragma` link syntax before for other things, but I am not using that for linking Boost (unless its automatically doing it somewhere). Is there somewhere in the project solution that I can see if the linker is using that?

Comment: The boost headers do that for you unless you turn that feature off.

Comment: The `CMakeList.txt` specifies `Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS`, and I can confirm that it is doing this process statically. I also added `#define BOOST_ALL_NO_LIB` to the source code, so I know that it is linking statically. However, this doesn't check if it is linking the debug or release libraries. I can't seem to find a way to explociitly tell Boost to use release mode libraries. Do you know of a way to do that?

Comment: Update: I ran it with ONLY the release mode libraries available to the linker, and I still get the same error.

Comment: Did you look at the code at line 23 yet of the destructor?

Comment: Yes, I edited the OG post to show that code as well. I don't see any problem with it. The problem seems to be coming from inside the destruction of either the `std::shared_ptr<udp::socket>` or the `io_service` object that a part of the `NetworkManager` class

Comment: Thanks. Yes it looks like this happens when the destructor goes out of scope.

Comment: I rebuilt boost to target DLL's and I get the same problem still. Does anyone know anything that could cause this kind of exception if async `udp::socket` calls?

Answer (score 1):

This problem was happening because the `io_service` object was being destroyed when my `NetworkManager` destructor was going out of scope. This was problematic because I was using `udp::socket::async_recvFrom`, which was still trying to access to the `io_service` object.

The problem can be solved by either passing in a reference to the `io_service` object and creating the socket via the default constructor, or, you can use a shared pointer to `io_service` and pass in that reference if you don't want to create the sockets right away.